# Remove first two entries per unique ID based on date

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with (among others) a column of unique ID's and interview dates. The data frame has many rows for each ID. I want to remove all rows that for the first two interview dates for each household id.

Thanks for the help!

EDIT: here is an example of what I'm working with:

In the table I would like to remove rows 1-4, 7-9,and 11-14 as they all occur within the first two interview dates for each ID.

```
dates=as.Date(c("1/1/12","1/1/12","1/5/12","1/5/12","1/7/12","1/7/12","2/1/12","2/1/12","2/5/12","6/1/12","6/3/12","6/3/12","6/4/12","6/4/12","6/15/12","6/15/12"),format='%m/%d/%y')
    hh_id=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3)
    df<-data.frame(hh_id,dates)
    arrange(df,hh_id,desc(dates))


 hh_id   dates
1      1  1/7/12
2      1  1/7/12
3      1  1/5/12
4      1  1/5/12
5      1  1/1/12
6      1  1/1/12
7      2  6/1/12
8      2  2/5/12
9      2  2/1/12
10     2  2/1/12
11     3  6/4/12
12     3  6/4/12
13     3  6/3/12
14     3  6/3/12
15     3 6/15/12
16     3 6/15/12
```

Comment: Please provide some code and a `?dput` of your data (probably only a few rows are enough (see `?head`))

Comment: Thanks- I've just added it in an edit above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'ID', we `order` the 'date' and use the `tail` function to remove the first two observations.

```
 library(data.table)
 setDT(df1)[order(date), tail(.SD, -2) , by = ID]
```

NOTE:

1) Assumed the 'date' column as `Date` class.  If not convert to `Date` class with `as.Date` by specifying the `format` (if not in the `YYYY-MM-DD`).

2) The column names and object name are fictitious.  Change that to the original column names/object names

---

Based on the update in the OP's post

```
setDT(df)[df[order(dates), .I[!(dates %in% dates[1:2])] ,hh_id]$V1]
```

Comment: I am looking to remove all rows that have the first two interview dates, not just the first two rows for each hh_id. sorry for the lack of clarity-I've fixed my question in the edit

Comment: @AshleyThomas  Updated the post